# How do you pass a nullable list of objects with Parcelable

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

I want to pass a custom object that has a nullable list of other custom objects. How do I go around passing this. I am using Kotlin

writeTypedList and createTypedArrayList do not work when the list is null

Comment: Not a direct answer, but how about using other ways of serializing objects? Example: Shared ViewModel, convert to json and back etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "writeTypedList and createTypedArrayList do not work when the list is null"? The `Parcel.writeTypedList()` method handles the null case (it writes a -1 size flag), and the `readTypedList()` method also handles it (it reads the size and returns null if it sees -1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite easy, you just need to read the list only if it's not null.

```
dest.writeByte(list == null ? (byte)0 : (byte)1)
if(list != null) {
    dest.writeInt(list.size());
    dest.writeTypedList(list);
}
```

Then

```
boolean hasList = in.readByte() > 0;
if(hasList) {
    int size = in.readInt();
    List<MyObj> list = new ArrayList<>(size);
    in.readTypedList(list, MyObj.CREATOR);
}
```

Comment: I don't mean to spam things up at all, but I'd caution against doing this because Android already does it for you. The source for Parcel.writeTypedList() shows that the system can already handle nulls (and does so by writing an int flag to the parcel): https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.0.0_r1/core/java/android/os/Parcel.java#1094

Comment: @BenP. I trust the source code but then I wonder what didn't work for the question asker.

Answer (score 0):

> How to send a list of custom objects which in turn consists of custom objects ?

You need to implement `Parcelable interface` for *each and every* custom object in the link that you have created.

```
dest.writeTypedList(customList) // in write to parcel
```

and

```
this.customList = in.createTypedArrayList(CustomObject.CREATOR) // in the constructor which receives (Parcel in) as parameter
```

Just remember **dont miss out any object** from implementing parcelable interface in the link.